# How to batch the deployment of multiple Safes?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Inspired by the Transaction builder app, I've been wondering if I could deploy multiple different Safes on Ethereum (only), in a batched way, from a single owner address.

Each Safe has 4 other signers and none of the signers change across the deployed Safes; in other words, the signers remain consistent across deployed Safes.

"Batched way" can mean two things here. One is to deploy, say 10 Safes at the same time but not necessarily via single transaction (weak way), or deployed in a single transaction (strong way).

Are either of these possible, and if so, how? Thanks a ton!